# Assign different values into a new column based on dataframe chunk

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],'b':[100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100]})

    a    b
0   1  100
1   2  100
2   3  100
3   4  100
4   5  100
5   6  100
6   7  100
7   8  100
8   9  100
9  10  100
```

I want to create a column `c`, such that for every chunk of 3 rows it assigns a value.

The output i'm looking for:

```
    a    b    c
0   1  100    1
1   2  100    1
2   3  100    1
3   4  100    2
4   5  100    2
5   6  100    2
6   7  100    3
7   8  100    3
8   9  100    3
9  10  100    4
```

I tried to iterate through the dataframe and then using .loc to assign column values.

Is there any better/quick way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

If your index is a RangeIndex you can use it to create your values for your c column:

```
df['c'] = df.index // 3 + 1
```

Comment: and, `(np.arange(0, len(df.index)) // 3) + 1` if `index` isn't continuous range.

Comment: No guarantee that the index is numeric, let alone integer.  better off using `np.arange(len(df)) // 3 + 1`